# EXCEL VBA or Function VLoopup - Based on Multiple Criteria to find the value

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to Vlookup using two criteria:

1. the value in Column D;
2. The amount in Column A and Column G which can be approximately matched.

The normal Vlookup only returns the value of the first row, so one solution I think about is to match both the Invoice Number and Approximately Match the amount.

I am not sure if it is the best solution, please advise a better one, not necessarily in VBA, it can also use INDEX or MATCH functions, etc.
Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Vlookup based on Multiple Criteria]

Below is the formula I've been trying, it is like something **If true, then this value, if false then Lookup the next one....** But I am still thinking about how to navigate though the Vlookup to search next value, do I need to use VBA to solve this?! [Vlookup based on Multiple Criteria2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4fqQ.png)

[image]

Comment: Why only the last row in this example? Is the because it's the last record for that Invoice No by Document Date?

Comment: No, sometimes an invoice number has multiple records, like 3, or 4 records, this is just to simply the case

Comment: Please show what you've tried.  There are many ways to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should work:

```
=INDEX(G3:G5,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((D3:D5=B3)*ROW(D3:D5)))-3,1)
```

That's just a fancier version of `Index(Match)` that is used as a common replacement for vlookup. In this case, instead of `Match` we use Sumproduct to get the max row with the criteria we are looking for.

**ADDED**: Added a `-3` to the second paramater of `INDEX` in order to adjust the `Row()` returned to the actual range that is being `Indexed`.

Comment: Hi JNevill, Thanks for your answer but it does not work, I have updated my solution with the logic, could you help to have a look?

Comment: I notice that I fetch the invoice number from that lookup, instead I have changed my formula in the answer to properly fetch the amount. If this doesn't work, please let me know what isn't work (the error you are receiving, or the value that is being returned incorrectly).

Comment: OK, your formula returns error "#REF", I figured out that the Ref should be G3:G5=B3

Comment: Possibly, that condition is where we look up the invoice number in the range. So if your invoice number is, in fact, in column G, then your change should work.

Comment: I mean this part MAX((D3:D5=B3) to MAX((G3:G5=B3)

Comment: Right.. that part `MAX((D3:D5=B3)*ROW(D3:D5))` looks for the invoice number from `b3` in the range `D3:D5`. If it finds it, it returns the `Row` that it's on. `Max()` then takes the max row returned from the multiple times it found a matching row and returns that up to the `INDEX` function. By changing it to `MAX((G3:G5=B3)*ROW(D3:D5))` you are saying "Find the invoice number in `B3` in the range `G3:G5` which is different then your screenshot.

Comment: OK, I am wrong. But it still does not work, returns error #REF, I don't know why to use the max function, because the record found may not be the in the last row, I've updated the quesion,

Comment: What do you get for output if you just run `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((D3:D5=B3)*ROW(D3:D5)))`

Comment: I added a picture to the question, what if the record is not in the last row

Comment: It returned me a '5' if I use =SUMPRODUCT(MAX((D3:D5=B3)*ROW(D3:D5)))

Comment: ah! lol I see what the problem is.. Check out the updated formula.

Comment: If the record isn't in the last row, then you would need to specify the criteria for determining that the second to last is the one you want. Like.. Why do you want that second to last one? Is it because it's first instance of that invoice on the last date found for the invoice? Or something like that. Otherwise it's just arbitrary.

Comment: OK, let me explain more, I need to calculate the difference between the two values after I have successfully done this. Actually I want to map the correct value using the invoice number, but, sometimes one invoice number links to several records, so I need to 1: Same invoice number; 2: A criteria to find the most approximate value (i.e. Column G compare to Column A)